# Set the display precision of a float in Ruby

Tags: ruby, floating-point, precision

Is it possible to set the display precision of a float in Ruby?

Something like:

```
z = 1/3
z.to_s    #=> 0.33333333333333
z.to_s(3) #=> 0.333
z.to_s(5) #=> 0.33333
```

Or do I have to override the `to_s` method of `Float`?

Comment: how about z.round(2), z.round(3) ?

Comment: round (with a precision) didn't exist at the time that this question was asked :)

Answer (score 93):

`z.round(2)` or `x.round(3)` is the simplest solution. See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Float.html#method-i-round.

That said, that will only ensure that it is no more than that many digits. In the case of 1/3 that is fine, but if you had say `0.25.round(3)` you will get 0.25, not 0.250.

Comment: FYI, this was added in Ruby 1.9.2, so it won't work with earlier versions

Comment: +1 for the note about `(0.25).round(3)` not yielding `0.250`  See Andreas Bonini's answer for a way around this.

Answer (score 53):

You can use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf("%0.02f", 123.4564564)
```

Comment: I prefer this for times when I want the ".00" that `round(2)` does not give.

Comment: This is kinda amusing, I never used ruby in my life. I don't know how to write a hello world program and never did. I probably just googled the OP's question and posted the answer.

Comment: `puts "Hello, World"` -- Haha! Now you know how to write a hello world program!

Comment: ...though using `puts` is a bit ironic since obviously `sprintf` works as well.

Comment: @KyleStrand what do you mean by using `puts` being ironic? What in it is happening in a way contrary to what is expected, and how is it causing wry amusement?

Comment: @MadisNõmme When I wrote that, I was apparently thinking that `sprintf` performed text output. If that were the case, it would have been ironic for AndreasBonini's first Ruby "hello world" not to use the text-output function that they have *already used successfully* in a previous complete, working Ruby program (the one-liner in this answer).

Answer (score 37):

I would normally just do the conversion in open code, something like:

```
puts "%5.2f" % [1.0/3.0]
```

Ruby calls [Kernel#format](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format) for expressions like this, because String has a [core operator % defined](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-25) on it.  Think of it as *printf for Ruby* if that rings any bells for you.

Comment: Can anyone explain this?

Comment: this one gave me a leading space character. I used Andreas's answer and it  did it without the space character. I couldn't grasp the documentation on this or else I'd explain why lol

Answer (score 6):

Rubocop recommends using [`#format`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-format) over `#sprintf` and using annotated string tokens.

The syntax for `#format` is

```
%[flags][width][.precision]type
```

Example:

```
# Ensure we store z as a float by making one of the numbers a float.
z = 1/3.0

# Format the float to a precision of three.
format('%<num>0.3f', num: z)
# => "0.333"

format('%<num>0.5f', num: z)
# => "0.33333"

# Add some text to the formatted string
format('I have $%<num>0.2f in my bank account.', num: z)
# => "I have $0.33 in my bank account."
```

References:

- https://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/RuboCop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/FormatString
- https://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/RuboCop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/FormatStringToken

Answer (score 3):

You can use puts

```
z = #{'%.3f' % z}
```