# Convert string to float with precision

Tags: ruby, string

When I convert string to float, how do I put a dot two houses before the end? This is a example of what I want to do.

```
"000001909".to_f  = 19.09
```

But I only get this:

```
"000001909".to_f  = 1909.0
```

Comment: but "000001909" is equals to 1909.0. No?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933958/set-the-display-precision-of-a-float-in-ruby

Comment: What is "two precisions before the end"?

Comment: Umm … divide by 100?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That string represents the value `1909` so merely `to_f`ing it won't work. You need to divide by 100.0 to move the decimal point over two "houses" as you so eloquently put it:

```
"000001909".to_f / 100.0 # => 19.09
```

Having a string with a dot in it will output the expected result as well:

```
"0000019.09".to_f # => 19.09
```